# JSON format for creating Jqwidgets dynamic column grid

Tags: php, json, jqwidget

I’m unable to get the valid JSON format for creating dynamic column grid.
Here is what I have:
PHP

```
$query="select * from mytable";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);

//Results:
[{"EmpID":"12345","Name":"James","Account":"New Account1","Group1":"Library","Food_Bill_Date":null,"Food_Bill_Amount":null,"Food_Bill_Number":null},
{"EmpID":"12346","Name":"David","Account":"New Account2","Group2":"Lab","Food_Bill_Date":null,"Food_Bill_Amount":null,"Food_Bill_Number":null},
{"EmpID":"12347","Name":"Ramsy","Account":"New Account2","Group2":"Lab","Food_Bill_Date":null,"Food_Bill_Amount":null,"Food_Bill_Number":null},
............
.............
............
]
```

[Jqwidgets Dynamic Column](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/dynamiccolumns.htm)

Need to separate rows and column from results array.

Required in

```
[
    {
        "columns": [
            {
                "text": "SampleK",
                "datafield": "sample1",
                "width": "30"
            },
            {
                "text": "ID",
                "datafield": "id",
                "width": "30"
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "rows": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Hot Chocolate",
                "type": "Chocolate Beverage",
                "calories": "370",
                "totalfat": "16g",
                "protein": "14g"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Peppermint Hot Chocolate",
                "type": "Chocolate Beverage",
                "calories": "440",
                "totalfat": "16g",
                "protein": "13g"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Please help.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to separate the column and row data in the output array (as show above), to feed the grid table as input. I tried to get the columns and rows data separately, but I'm unable to achieve.